# export 'BrowserRoute' (imported as 'BrowserRoute') was not found in 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my **app.js** file.

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRoute, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Box } from '@mui/material'

import { Navbar, Feed, VideoDetail, SearchFeed, ChannelDetail } from './components/index'

const App = () => {
  (
    <BrowserRoute>
      <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: '#000' }}>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' exact element={<Feed />} />
          <Route path='/video/:id' element={<VideoDetail />} />
          <Route path='/channel/:id' element={<ChannelDetail />} />
          <Route path='/search/:searchTerm' element={<SearchFeed />} />
        </Routes>
      </Box>

    </BrowserRoute>
  )
}

export default App
```

& I am getting error like this:

```
export 'BrowserRoute' (imported as 'BrowserRoute') was not found in 'react-router-dom' 
export 'default' (reexported as 'Navbar') was not found in './Navbar' (possible exports: Navbar)
export 'default' (reexported as 'VideoDetail') was not found in './VideoDetail' (possible exports: VideoDetail)
```

**index.js** file from which I am trying to import the components is:

```
export { default as Navbar } from './Navbar'
export { default as ChannelDetail } from './ChannelDetail'
export { default as VideoDetail } from './VideoDetail'
export { default as SearchFeed } from './SearchFeed'
export { default as Feed } from './Feed'
```

**What should I do...?**

Comment: Please post your `Navbar` component code.

Comment: There is no BrowserRoute component, I believe you are missing the 'r' at the end. It should be BrowserRouter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the `BrowserRouter` import error, you need to fix a typo in your import. It's `BrowserRouter` with an "r", not `BrowserRoute`.

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
```